# JS Как сделать функцию которая будет отслеживать элемент, и в случае нужного элемента выполнять функцию

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
const switchLike = document.querySelector('.elements__like');
switchLike.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const image = switchLike.getAttribute('src')
        if (image === './img/like.svg') {
            switchLike.removeAttribute('src');
            switchLike.setAttribute('src', './img/blacklike.svg');
        } else {
            switchLike.removeAttribute('src');
            switchLike.setAttribute('src', './img/like.svg');
        }
})
```

Функция работает для одного элемента, а у меня их n-ое количество задачи функции менять 1 картинку на другую. Теперь нужно сделать для всех. Я так понимаю нужна функция в которую мы поместим цикл со всеми элементами, и при использовании элемента вызовем функцию замены. Но реализовать не получается(

Comment: Сделайте сниппет, который можно запустить на сайте.

Comment: а все эти элементы внутри одного общего элемента? если общий охватывающий элемент есть -  поставьте обработчик на охватывающий их элемент и потом по event.target  внутри меняйте параметр нужный вам.  Все события же всплывают до элемента body. Смысл отдельные обработчики ставить, если логика схожая по обработке для всех элементов?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону `наблюдатель js` по вопросу > отслеживать элемент, и в случае нужного элемента выполнять функцию

**MutationObserver: наблюдатель за изменениями**

---

**Intersection Observer API позволяет веб-приложениям асинхронно следить за изменением пересечения элемента с его родителем или областью видимости документа viewport.**

---

**ResizeObserver API — это интерфейс слежения за изменениями размеров элемента. Это своего рода аналог события window.resize для элемента.**

Comment: Добавлю, что ваша задача не относится к вопросу про отслеживания. Вы просто хотите функцию написать, которая бы вам меняла много картинок, работая  в цикле.

Создайте массив путей, пройдитесь циклом по массиву и на каждой итерации добавляйте  img ${href}, где  href - это элемент массива + декструризация.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.elements__like').forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const image = this.getAttribute('src');
    if (image === './img/like.svg') {
      this.removeAttribute('src');
      this.setAttribute('src', './img/blacklike.svg');
    } else {
      this.removeAttribute('src');
      this.setAttribute('src', './img/like.svg');
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: А зачем удалять каждый раз атрибут? Мы же его перезаписываем все равно, даже если так, удаление можно вынести перед блоком if/else.

Answer (score -1):

Предлагаю посмотреть документацию, по поводу ДОМ и как с ним работать.

пару сслыок:

Ваш вариант

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

а вот еще

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

ну и эта тоже

https://medium.com/@adrior/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-queryselector-%D0%B8-queryselectorall-58c4ddf44df2

если ответа в них нет, то значит нужно подумать о другом подходе ;)

Удачи!

Comment: Если ваша идея была взять через querySelectorAll все элементы elements__like то ничего не получится. Даже если бы и получилось то тогда все элементы при каждом клике меняли бы картинку, а не каждый по отдельности, увы(

Comment: ну что ж попробую еще раз)
1. было бы не плохо если бы вы предоставили больше инфы/ условий, что нужно сделать + какой-то приближенный к реальности пример.. то что js эт хорошо, может у вас в задаче сложная структура дом-дерева.. 
2. я лишь подсказал источник, который мог бы дать пищи на размышление, в случае если вообще никто ничего не подскажет... а если понимаете разницу между querySelector и querySelectorAll и знаете какие еще способы есть, как работать с дом, то - эт круто! 
3. Вот что понял из условия, то и написал- https://jsfiddle.net/dimakacer/d58qaksm/